# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении и почему?

"Такой процесс как строительство своего объекта, очень сложно отдать на аутсорсинг и отрешенно наблюдать за ним со стороны".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: "Такой процесс, как строительство своего объекта, очень сложно отдать на аутсорсинг и отрешенно наблюдать за ним со стороны".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Всегда обособляются обороты с повтором вида ТАК…КАК, ТАКОЙ…КАК,а также обороты с союзами КАК  И, КАК…ТАК  И, например:

Редко встретишь такого интересного человека, как он. Я никогда не видел леса таким прекрасным, как в эту ночь. В лесу зимой так красиво, как в сказке.  Здесь пахло маслом так же крепко, как в церкви. И разве так, как теперь, жил Париж! Вдохновение нужно в геометрии, как  и в поэзии.